# O que é XHTML e quando deve ser usado?

Tags: html, xml, xhtml

O que eu sei é que o XHTML precisa ser XML válido. Isso implica, por exemplo, que todas as tags precisam ser fechadas. Por exemplo:

```
Errado:
<br>

Certo:
<br/>
```

Porém, qual é a utilidade disto? Pra que ele serve? Quando deve ser usado?

Comment: XHTML é o padrão utilizado na construção de livros eletrônicos como o mobi da amazon e o epub. Basicamente os e-books seguem este padrão para que haja portabilidade entre os dispositivos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basicamente o XHTML é uma reformulação do HTML baseado em XML, com todas as suas regras e validações.

Qual é a utilidade?
Alguns dispositivos não reconhecem o HTML, pois ele não possui um sentido semântico.

Quando deve ser usado?
Se deseja que sua aplicação seja vista em todos os lugares (TV, palm, celular, etc), o XHTML é o caminho correto.

Comment: Atualmente o Xhtml está incorporado no HTML5 que é o padrão a ser seguido.

Comment: @MarceloAymone, está dizendo que posso usar JSF com HTML5 ao invés de XHTML?

Comment: JSF 2.2 já tem suporte sim.
http://www.codigosfontes.com.br/jsf-2-2-html-5-jquery-bootstrap-15-minutos/

Answer (score 5):

XHTML é HTML escrito de acordo com as regras do XML. Como o XML é bem mais estrito do que o HTML, a ideia é que você escreva uma sintaxe sem erros. XML é uma linguagem de marcação bem genérica. Diferente do HTML,  XML permite que você faça suas próprias tags. Hoje, isso não faz mais tanto sentido já que temos outras maneiras de estruturar dados, como o JSON, por exemplo.

E essa era a grande sacada: um arquivo XHTML é um HTML e também um XML. Isso quer dizer que a extração de dados seria bem mais fácil. Imagine que você poderia extrair dados de qualquer página web como se estivesse fazendo uma requisição a um arquivo XML. Interessante, mas não muito útil para época. Outra coisa é que para um XHTML ser realmente útil, ele precisa ser servido com o `application/xhtml+xml` MimeType, o que ninguém fazia. Quando o HTML5 surgiu, por rebeldia de um grupo de desenvolvedores ligados a vários *browsers*, o cenário mudou bastante. o HTML5 resolvia de verdade alguns problemas que tínhamos há anos no desenvolvimento web.

Contudo, como o HTML5 é totalmente retrocompatível, você consegue usar seu XHTML hoje como se fosse HTML normal. A sintaxe do XHTML não vai quebrar seu site e você estará livre de problemas. Hoje, ninguém usa XHTML, por isso, não há indicação ou sugestão para que você use em seus projetos.

Answer (score 3):

Uma outra aplicação do XHTML é na geração dinâmica de conteúdo. Você pode, por exemplo, interpretar com JavaScript um arquivo XML que representa uma parte de uma página. Aplicações web de grande acesso usam esta estratégia para tirar proveito da *cache*.
Por exemplo: o menu, que é algo que não muda frequentemente, pode ser renderizado dinamicamente por um JavaScript a partir de um mix de CSS e XHTML, onde a porção com XHTML está em um arquivo `.xml` e o a formatação em um `.css`. Nesta situação é possível forçar o *cache* destes dois arquivos no *browser*, economizando recursos caros, tais como links de internet e processamento no *web server*.

Se puder, assista a esta apresentação:
https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/1939-asynchronous-systems-architecture-for-the-web
O inglês é relativamente fácil e o palestrante é o Udi Dahan, um arquiteto .Net reconhecido mundialmente. Vale a pena!

Comment: Nunca tinha me tocado em relação a isso! Obrigado por compartilhar.

Comment: Boa dica! +1 :)